# Can This Matrix Proof Be Done Without the Definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following was taken from Stephen Friedberg's Linear Algebra, 2nd Edition.

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix, $B$ and $C$ be $n \times p$ matrices. 
Show that $A(B+C) = AB + BC$ and, for any $k \in F$, $k(AB) = (kA)B = A(kB)$.

Proof:  $[ A(B+C) ]_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ik}(B+C)_{kj}$ 
$= \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj} + \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ik}C_{kj} = (AB)_{ij} + (BC)_{ij} = [AB + BC]_{ij}$

I did the second part myself:  We have $[k(AB)]_{ij} = k \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj}$ 
$ = \sum_{i=1}^n kA_{ik}B_{kj} = \sum_{i=1}^n (kA)_{ik}B_{kj}$ 
$ = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ik}kB_{kj} = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ik}(kB)_{kj}$ 
As a result, $k(AB) = (kA)B = A(kB)$.

I noticed that the proof used the definition of matrix addition and scalar multiplication.  $(B+C)_{ij} = B_{ij} + C_{ij}$ and $(kA)_{ij} = k(A)_{ij}$.  Now is it possible to prove without the definitions? 
I became curious because Mr. Friedberg introduced the matrix as a representation of a linear transformation over an ordered basis.  So, I tried proving via the linear transformation over an ordered basis and could not do it.  For example:

Let $\alpha = \{x_1, x_2 ... x_n\}$ be an ordered basis of $V, \gamma = \{z_1, z_2 ... z_m\}$ be an ordered basis of $W$, 
and $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation.  Elsewhere, Mr. Friedberg already defined that $(kT)(x_j) = kT(x_j)$.  Suppose that $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$.

$k(A) = k *[ \space T(x_1) \space T(x_2) \space ... \space T(x_n) \space ] = [\space kT(x_1) \space kT(x_2) \space ... \space kT(x_n) \space ] = [ \space (kT)(x_1) \space (kT)(x_2) \space ... \space (kT)(x_n) \space]$

But this is possible only because of the definition of scalar multiplication.

Comment: I am confused what you are asking. Are you asking to show matrix multiplication distributes over matrix addition without defining what the operations are?

Comment: @OwenSizemore:  Now that you frame the question this way, I can see how stupid my endeavor was.  I guess I haven't fully understood the idea that a matrix is a linear transformation over an ordered basis.

Comment: This question is relevant: [Proving Distributivity of Matrix Multiplication](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464151/proving-distributivity-of-matrix-multiplication/464172#464172).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not possible to do so without using the definition directly.  Given that we're including non-square matrices, we have the properties:

\begin{align*}
A+B &= B+A & \text{addition is commutative} \\
A+(B+C) &= (A+B)+C & \text{addition is associative} \\
A+\mathbf{0} &= A & \text{existence of all-0 matrix} \\
\mathbf{0}+A &= A & \\
A+(-A) &= \mathbf{0} & \text{existence of additive inverse} \\
(-A)+A &= \mathbf{0} & \\
A(BC) &= (AB)C & \text{multiplication is associative} \\
(A+B)C &= AC+BC & \text{multiplication is right-distributive}
\end{align*}
and want to prove $A(B+C)=AB+AC$.  If we input these as axioms into [Mace4](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/),  we obtain the model:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
+ & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\times & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
and we see that in this algebraic structure $1 \times (0+0)=1$ whereas $1 \times 0+1 \times 0=0$, so this algebraic structure does not have the left-distributive property.

Hence there is an algebraic structure which is consistent with all the above properties, but which is not left-distributive.

Hence, it is impossible to prove left-distributivity from the above axioms alone.  (Any proof would equally disprove the existence of the above model, which exists.)

---

If we restrict to square matrices, we can add in the axioms:

\begin{align*}
A+I &= A & \text{existence of identity} \\
I+A &= A & \\
\end{align*}

With this restriction the above model does not work; this time Mace4 gives the model:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\times & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
$$

We check $2 \times (0+0)=2$ and $2 \times 0 + 0 \times 2=0$.  So again we have a non-left-distributive algebraic structure that satisfies all of the other axioms.

---

*Caveat*: It's possible that I've not included some axioms that would then allow left-distributivity to be proved (most notably axioms of scalar multiplication, which is not easy to input into Mace4).  However, hopefully the message is still clear: it's likely there is an algebraic structure that is consistent with the remaining axioms (without being left-distributive), in which case those axioms are insufficient to prove left-distributivity.