# Is $A^2-A=A(A-I)$ in matrices?

Tags: matrices

Is $A^2-A=A(A-I)$ in matrices?

Thanks !

Comment: Matrix multiplication is distributive, yes.

Comment: Why did you write the same thing 5 times?

Comment: You only have to ask it once. You only have to ask it once. You only have to ask it once. You only have to ask it once. You only have to ask it once.

Comment: [Proving Distributivity of Matrix Multiplication](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464151/proving-distributivity-of-matrix-multiplication) contains a couple of proofs that matrix multiplication is (left) distributive over sum. First couple of lines of the accepted answer should do.